# Choosing Appcelerator for Force.com App

Tags: force.com, mobile, appcelerator

I am planning to develop a mobile app using Appcelerator and force.com platform. I am new to Appcelerator platform and my top fear is stablity of Appcelerator connector, because of following reasons

1. Its not part of core salesforce  mobile sdk, I doubt its regularly updated and maintained.
2. On the [connector listing](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/836?1770723010) it says "iOS" as  supported operating system. Does this means no other os like Android, Windows etc are supported ?

**My goal is to get native looking app, rather HTML for performance and other reasons**. So I am opting for Appcelerator as it gives native binaries, otherwise could have opted for PhoneGap.

Based on above summary, can any experienced developers recommend me going forward on this path with Appcelerator ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a part of the Appceleator Titans community, I'd like to chime in here as well.

1) IMO, the Appcelerator connector CAN NOT be a part of the Mobile SDK unless they add flexibility to support multiple frameworks. You should view it similar to the recently launched Mobile Packs for other JS frameworks.

2) Yes, I believe this is iOS only for now. +1 on Kevin's suggestion regarding building your own oAuth dance. The plugin is NOT certified to work on Titanium 3.x - it states compatibility with Titanium 2.0 and Titanium 1.8

I'm already working with Salesforce folks for helping build a Sencha Touch Mobile Pack. I can definitely consider spending time on get something working on Titanium 3.x - will keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at implementing your own oAuth flow - it's actually not super difficult.  I did this a while back, you can look at how I did it here:

https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/Force

You can interact with the web view control directly to grab the authorization token.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for pointers, i'll check this out. So it means we need to add OAuth flows, I thought its already done and we need to put consumer keys in it, based on this example on developerforce: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Developing_Mobile_Applications_with_Force.com_and_Appcelerator_Titanium

Answer (score 1):

> On the connector listing it says "iOS" as supported operating system. Does this means no other os like Android, Windows etc are supported ?

Yes, I would take that as meaning only iOS, not Android, Windows or BBerry.

I'd advise you to go to the [SF Mobile Developer WIKI page](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Mobile_SDK) and follow some of the links to learn about the latest and greatest that was released just last month during Mobile Developer Week.

Comment: +1 thanks @crmprogdev, I am very much in touch with Salesforce Mobile updates, its having a lot of goodies, but none match my requirements i.e. Native Binaries for all platforms, phone gap can do that, but its HTML internally :(